# Calculate difference between row values in dataframe based on row value in other column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I calculate the difference between row values for each year, starting the calculation anew when the year changes?

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011],
               'measurement1': [1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6], 
              'measurement2': [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4]})
```

The year is set as the index in the data frame so that no difference is calculated between the years.
`df = df.set_index('year')`

The result that I would like to get, is the following dataframe:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011],
               'measurement1': [0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3], 
              'measurement2': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2]})
```

You can see that the difference is calculated between the rows during each year. When we have a measurement for a new year, the calculation starts again from new. If using the .diff method, the difference is also calculated between the values of the consecutive years.

How can I calculate the difference between the values only measured during one year?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas `groupby` to group by year and then apply `diff()`

```
grouped = df.groupby("year").diff()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the transformation is not trivial, I would define a function:

```
def delta(x):
    y = (x.shift().bfill() - x)
    return(np.where(y>=0, y, -y))
```

Then `groupby` `transform` will to the job:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011],
               'measurement1': [1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6], 
              'measurement2': [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4]}).set_index('year')

df_resul = df.groupby(level=0).transform(delta).astype(int)
```

it gives:

```
      measurement1  measurement2
year                            
2010             0             0
2010             2             1
```

(just use `reset_index` to get your expected dataframe)